# Android WebView activity is slow on initial start

Tags: android, performance, caching, webview

I am using WebView to show local data.
Html file itself is about 800kb + 400images(60MB in total).  Activity which is containing the Webview is closed each time after it's used.
Loading takes 4 to 10 (each time)seconds depending on device that is used.

I have tried the following
enabling caching. 
Increase the renderers priority.
with no/little effect.

Other things I tried but was unable to get it working.
1)  I tried caching the WebViewActivity 
meaning activity is removed from stack but I have it in memory and have reference to it.

2) Load the Webview (with local data) only once  in application context or within a service
inject this Webwervice in the layout when the activity(using the webview) is called.

Searching google and stack overflow didn't help too.

My question is.
Is it possible to load data within webview outside the activity?
how can i cache the acitivity(containing the webview)?
Does someone have an idea on how to fix this problem.

PS: splitting the html is not an option.

Comment: is it a static page?

Comment: yes (static local data).